# ViewPanel sortable column using Relational Data

Tags: xpages

I recently attended the "Access Data from XPages with the Relational Controls" webinar hosted by Teamstudio and presented by TLCC.  It was a very informative class and one topic covered was about enabling a column to be sortable in ASC/DESC order by simply clicking the column header.

Well, in a project I am currently working on we do have a DB2 backend where the viewPanel data uses a jdbcQuery with the sqlQuery parameter.  I thought this was possible when starting the project and could never get it to work, then after seeing it discussed during the webinar figured I would give it another attempt.

**Here are the All Properties for my viewPanel:**
[image: All Properties for viewPanel with datasource]

**Here are the All Properties for the column I wish to sort:**
[image: All Properties for viewPanel column]
**Previewed in IE with column Unsorted**

[image: IE Preview of Unsorted column]

**Previewed in IE with column sorted ASC**

[image: IE Preview of Sorted column]

**Problem**

Clicking on the column heading sorts the column in ASC order, but on subsequent clicks doesn't sort in DESC or reset the sort.

**Question**

Is there something I am missing to make this work or was this issue fixed in a version after 8.5.3?

**System**

IBM Notes Designer: 8.5.3FP3

OS: Windows/Longhorn/64 6.2

Server Build: Release 8.5.3FP6

Comment: This could be a 9.0.x feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking out the scope on your data (you have request).

Comment: I gave this a try and it did indeed work. Then after talking with Steve Zavocki I figured that if that would work using view for the scope should work and it also did work.  **So, the correct answer is have no value for the scope or use view because request scope is cleared when the partial refresh is performed on the viewPanel results to resort.**